# Setting icon in Beamer button

Tags: beamer, fontawesome

Let's say I have the following MWE (from [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/08/16/beamer-series-pt3.html)):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \hyperlink{contents}{\beamerbutton{contents page}}

    \hyperlink{columns}{\beamergotobutton{columns page}}

    \hyperlink{pictures}{\beamerskipbutton{pictures page}}

    \hyperlink{pictures}{\beamerreturnbutton{Home page}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It gives this:

[image]

Now, I want to change the left triangle icon (just before `Home page`) by another symbol (say, by `\faHome` from [`fontawesome`](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/fonts/fontawesome/doc/fontawesome.pdf) package). How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default definition of these symbols can be found in `beamerbasenavigation.sty`. So for example if you want to modify the symbol for your home page, which uses the `returnbutton`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\def\insertreturnsymbol{%
  \faCoffee\space
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \hyperlink{contents}{\beamerbutton{contents page}}

    \hyperlink{columns}{\beamergotobutton{columns page}}

    \hyperlink{pictures}{\beamerskipbutton{pictures page}}

    \hyperlink{pictures}{\beamerreturnbutton{Home page}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(the other symbols can be altered in the same way)